# Move Large tables between databases

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables in a 1.2 TB database on SQL server 2019 and want to move them to a new database .

First table is (171 GB Data , 45 GB indexs and 750 Millions rows)

second table is (24 GB Data , 55 GB Indexs and 300 Millions rows)

What is the best way to perform this task with minimal downtime ?

Comment: Why are you moving the tables in the first place? Are you archiving old stuff? Are the tables being updated? Is the new database located on same server? What are the source and destination server specs?

Comment: @vonPryz  This is a business requirment  to take these 2 tables to it's own database not my call. the new databse will be on the same server 
yes these tables are  heavy read and write

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server?

Comment: Why would the Business care /where/ the tables are stored?  That's not their responsibility (it's the DBA's!)  
Another Database on the /same/ server will free up precisely *nothing*, resource-wise.  Same instance, same processor, slightly different data files.  No real change.  
What is this [so-called] Requirement?  It /can't/ be Performance.  Security, perhaps?

Comment: Also, what isolation level are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the key here is '*minimal downtime*'
To achieve it you need to do it in two steps

- online initial load
- offline final sync

I guess the tables do have primary key or set of fields what could work as primary key. So after initial load you should

- delete rows in the destination not existing in source (deleted after initial load)
- update rows in the destination which have the same primary key but difference in data
- insert new records to destination

Another way to do it will be to setup transaction replication so initial load will be performed by snapshot agent and following synchronization will be performed based on transaction log.

Don't forget to remove the replication after migration.